# Possible to retrieve jQuery data?

Tags: jquery, data-binding, data-structures

I was wondering:

**Is it possible to retrieve data from other websites that is loaded and displayed with jQuery (or AJAX) from a database?**

Since jQuery is executed client-side; it must be possible somehow to receive the data before jQuery actually handles it right?

For example, what I'd like to do is read the 'heights' of the skycrapers in the following link:

http://www.pennystocktweets.com/stocks/top_100_graph

Where the only jQuery I could find that actually loads the data is:

```
/* function to initiate load more*/
function initLoadMore() {

var load_type = "more";
var oldestPostId = jQuery("#old_post_id").val();
var latestPostId = jQuery("#last_post_id").val();
var ProfileUserOrStockName = jQuery("#profile_usname").val();
var filter_type = jQuery("#category").val();
jQuery("#ploading_more_img").show(); 
// now set ajax calls
var post_data = {'cat':filter_type, "lptyp": load_type, "opid": oldestPostId, "lpid": latestPostId, "usrstk": ProfileUserOrStockName};
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
        url: "/user_posts/feeds",
        data: post_data,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function(feeds) {
            var feeds = jsonObjectify(feeds);
            if(feeds.psts != null) {
                processAppendData(feeds);
                jQuery("#ploading_more_img").hide(); 
            } else {
                jQuery("ShowMorePosts").html("No posts show");
            }
        }
}); 
return false;
}
```

From [this JavaScript file](http://www.pennystocktweets.com/js/feeds_handler.js?1380371752).

Now if I query with the following URL:

```
http://www.pennystocktweets.com/user_posts/feeds
```

I get a readable format for the tweets on the current page.

Now I would I go about imitating the AJAX call to a url call (executable from Java)?

The parameters are obviously:

```
var post_data = {'cat':filter_type, "lptyp": load_type, "opid": oldestPostId, "lpid": latestPostId, "usrstk": ProfileUserOrStockName};
```

But I can't seem to imitate the request. Can somebody with AJAX knowledge help out?

Comment: When you say Java, did you mean JavaScript, or literally Java. Java would be an option as it's server-side and not subject to the same origin policy, however JavaScript on the otherhand will be useless unless you have control over the remote site.

Comment: @KevinB: No I really mean Java NOT JavaScript

Comment: First, figure out exactly how the other website is getting that information. Does it come preloaded on the page somewhere, or does it get pulled in with ajax. Once you know that, you can then scrape it with java.

Comment: @KevinB: I have no idea where to start. Do you have any websites/articles/stack-questions that could help me get started?

Comment: Not really. All i can think of is start learning how to use the javascript debugger. All the information you need to figure out where the data is coming from can be found in that debugger.

Comment: @KevinB: But then how can I scrape the data?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Java, but essentially you'd just send an http request to the location that returns the data, then use string manipulation to extract the data from the returned text.

Comment: @KevinB: So retrieve the source with the debugger and then query the link for the info. Seems legit. Thanks for helping me get started!

Comment: @KevinB: Can you help me out with my new updated question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Apparently the AJAX calls used a remote URL to access the database.

I was able to reproduce the call by using [Fiddler web debugger](http://fiddler2.com/) and then looking for the outgoing `GET` (Ajax) calls to this remote location.

[image]
[image]

After multiple query's I found out the used syntax to make the calls.

So in this case, the solution was finding the exact URL and then imitate the GET call.